# How can I return a non empty response using Nest JS api and postman

Tags: node.js, typescript, api, promise, nestjs

I am using Nest Js to setup my server. I tried to fetch data from Postman to test if the API urls work. However I find that I get empty response from the server or undefined value from the postman request. The below code is the **users.controller.ts**

```
import {
  Body,
  Controller,
  Delete,
  Get,
  Header,
  Param,
  Post,
  Put,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { User } from './users.entity';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@Controller('users')
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private usersService: UsersService) {}
  /* @Get('/api/users')
  index(): string {
    return 'This will return user.';
  } */
  @Get()
  index(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.usersService.findUsers();
  }

  @Post('create')
  @Header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  async create(@Body() userData: User): Promise<any> {
    console.log(userData.UserId, userData.UserType + ' Check if working');
    return this.usersService.create(userData);
  }

  @Put(':userid/update')
  async update(@Param('userid') userid, @Body() userData: User): Promise<any> {
    userData.UserId = Number(userid);
    console.log('Update #' + userData.UserId);
    return this.usersService.update(userData);
  }

  @Delete(':userid/delete')
  async delete(@Param('userid') userid): Promise<any> {
    return this.usersService.delete(userid);
  }
}
```

and this code is users.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './users.entity';
import { UpdateResult, DeleteResult } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User) private userRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}

  async findUsers(): Promise<User[]> {
    return await this.userRepository.find();
  }

  async create(user: User): Promise<User> {
    console.log(user.UserType + 'User type');
    return await this.userRepository.save(user);
  }

  async update(user: User): Promise<UpdateResult> {
    return await this.userRepository.update(user.UserId, user);
  }

  async delete(userid): Promise<DeleteResult> {
    return await this.userRepository.delete(userid);
  }
}
```

If you can see the **post** request, there is a console.log()  to check whether there is a response or not. Hence I am getting an undefined value instead. I am seeking for support to understand where I am going wrong. I am not able to traceback the error as well.

Comment: you're not awaiting any of your async calls in your controller. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

You are not logging what your service returns, instead you are logging what your service receives as the body of the request:

```js
@Post('create')
@Header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
async create(@Body() userData: User): Promise<any> {

    // ##################################
    // here, you are logging userData, which is the object your 
    // service receives as input
    // ##################################
    console.log(userData.UserId, userData.UserType + ' Check if working');
    return this.usersService.create(userData);
}
```

If that `console.log` line is logging `undefined`, it means you are not sending the right data in your HTTP Post request body in postman.

You should be sending a `User` json object as the request payload.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and solved it by annotating my return object.

```
export class CriarTarefaDto  {

public nome: string;
public ativo?: boolean;

}
```

This was my object that always returned me empty when checking the return of the @Body annotation. I fixed it by including [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) lib annotations in my DTO properties.

```
import { IsBoolean, IsString } from 'class-validator';

export class CriarTarefaDto  {

@IsString()
public nome: string;

@IsBoolean()
public ativo?: boolean;

}
```

In your DTO object you need to use some annotation or extend the DTO with classes that register its properties.